# VBA Excel Timer Module

Tags: excel, vba

Problem : I need a 25 minute timer to countdown from a referenced time which is calculated by systemtime + 25mins. Once this 25 minute timer has completed I need a timer to pop up say that this timer is completed.

Currently the referenced time is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As    Boolean)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1,B11:B18,B20"))
    Cancel = True
    Target.Formula = Time
 End If
End Sub
```

Thanks !

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do i make the timer module ?

Comment: So i need the timer to start from the cell that has the referenced system time.

Comment: I agree @LioraHaydont. It is not clear what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to run something like

```
Application.OnTime Now()+TimeValue("00:25:00"), "EndTimer"
```

somewhere in your code, perhaps as

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As    Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1,B11:B18,B20")) Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Formula = Time ' This line is only if you want it to update the cell

        Application.OnTime Now()+TimeValue("00:25:00"), "EndTimer"
    End If
End Sub
```

and then have a procedure

```
Sub EndTimer()
    MsgBox "Time has ended"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

So if i need to place this into the VBA backend do I add this as a module ?

Comment: And if i want this to start as soon as a double click is made on a certain box which adds the system time do I then need to reference this field ?

Comment: @LChartersLeahy I think the edit I just made would work.